# Modify dataframes in list with R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I want to work on columns and row-names of a bunch of data frames, say *W1*, *W2*, *W3*, whose names are listed in a previously built list, say *W*. I've seen quite a few similar questions, but none seem to address my difficulty:

```
>  W <- list(W1, W2, W3)
>  lapply(W, is.data.frame)
$W1
[1] TRUE
$W2
[1] TRUE
$W3
[1] TRUE
```

Ultimately what I want to do is:

```
>  lapply(W, function(x) rowname(x) = x[,1])
>  lapply(W, function(x) x = x[,-1])
```

- defines row-names for each data-frame using its first column values.
- suppress the first column after that,

but in both cases I get the content of the first column for each data frame. I'm missing something basic...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just combine the two steps into one `lapply`. Remember that in R a function will return the last thing it evaluates, so in your first `lapply` it is just going to return the `rownames` of each data.frame since that's the last thing the function did. Adding `x[,-1]` after that makes it return the modified data.frame, minus the first column.

```
W1 <- data.frame(a=letters[1:3], b=1:3, c=4:6)
W2 <- data.frame(a=letters[4:5], b=4:5, c=5:6)
W3 <- data.frame(a=LETTERS[1:5], b=1:5, c=11:15)
W <- list(W1, W2, W3)

W <- lapply(W, function(x) {
    row.names(x) <- x[,1]
    x[,-1]
})
```

Comment: Tx. I took the liberty to edit your answer in order to make it a working solution. **1/** typo in x[,-1] which you wrote as [x,-1] and **2/** added assignment to W as W <- lapply( ... ) to make changes definitive.

Answer (score 1):

With *`tidyverse`* using @Taiki-Sakai's data:

```
library(tidyverse)
map(W, column_to_rownames, "a") # use remove_rownames(W) if relevant
# [[1]]
#   b c
# a 1 4
# b 2 5
# c 3 6
# 
# [[2]]
#   b c
# d 4 5
# e 5 6
# 
# [[3]]
#   b  c
# A 1 11
# B 2 12
# C 3 13
# D 4 14
# E 5 15
#
```

Comment: Hi Antoine and tx. Yr proposed solution works but why bring in yet another package when you can do that with base package tools at only a slightly greater typing cost... Thriftiness rules.

Comment: You're absolutely right that you shouldn't attach a new package for a quick task that can be done in base R. However these small tasks are usually part of a bigger project. If overall you see value in purrr and attach it for a given project, this solution is a compact and readable alternative so I believe some may find value in it.